# WSO2 ESB: Unable to load DB connection properties from registry

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have a car file named basic.car. This has a registry project named basicRegistry. I have created localentry type registry resource in this project, and named it DB_DRIVER and gave its value as "org.postgresql.Driver" in gov(also tried the same for conf)

Now in dblookup mediator properties, I chose "registry based driver config" and entered the value as

But when the car is deployed it shows the below error.

[2020-02-17 16:41:03,277] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.db.DBLookupMediator} - Error DB Mediator datasource: null.Registry entry defined with key: gov:dbconfig/DB_DRIVER not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To further analyze could you please provide the following information

- ESB version
- Synapse configurations related to DB lookup mediator
- Do you deploy the DBLookup mediator in a separate car file?

The car files are deployed in alphabetical order. If the registry resources and the DBlookup mediator configurations are deployed by two different car files make sure that registry resources are deployed prior to the synapse artifacts